# How to determine peak repetitions in a time series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

Assume there's a time series where peaks have been identified by some means as shown in the graph below. These could be voltage spikes recorded from some machine on an assembly line.

[image: Figure 1]

Visually one can look at the graph and see that the higher and lower amplitude peaks each repeat with some regularity.
What would be the proper technique(s) that would take the time series as input and output results that indicate that there are peak repetitions at intervals A and B.
Maybe A is 4 and B is 2 - the unit of measure doesn't matter (seconds, mins, etc)

Would it be autocorrelation, maybe something else?
My goal is to be programatically determine the set of peak repetitions that exist in the time series.

Comment: Are those unknown time intervals fixed or can they vary within each repetition?

Comment: @RobertL Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.